# Add an endnote inside a footnote in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, footnote

I have a Word document with both footnotes and endnotes.  I want to create an endnote reference from inside the text of a footnote.  When I am editing the footnote the option on the References menu to "Insert EndNote" is disabled.  Is there another way to add an endnote inside a footnote?